# Base64 encoded string to file (Ruby on Rails) - undefined method `unpack' Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, base64, activesupport, unpack

In one of my Rails controllers I am trying to take a Base64 encoded string, decode it and write it to a file (.png). Here is my code:

```
def create_character
    @character = Character.new(params[:character])
    @base64 = params[:base64]
    File.open("app/assets/images/characters/#{@character.name.gsub(/\s+/, "")}-#{@character.author_name.gsub(/\s+/, "")}.png", 'wb') do |f|
        f.write(Base64.decode64(@base64))
    end

    if @character.save
        flash[:notice] = "Character created."
        redirect_to(:action => 'share')
    else
```

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `unpack' for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x1044b22d8>
```

What is going wrong here?

Edit: One REALLY strange thing is that the code to write the file works perfectly fine in rails console but not when running the application.

Comment: What output do you get when you log or print the `@base64` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to pass a hash into the decode method. Are you sure you shouldn't be doing `@base64 = params[:character][:base64]`?

Answer (score 0):

I had an `unpack` error when I modified the data type from string to text.